# Azure Active Directory B2C Integration

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have created my application but now I want to use login functionality of a **Azure Active Directory B2C** now how to integrate the login process in my application??
Please guide me I already checked the **Azure Active-Directory-B2C** sign up and sign in process with the help of Microsoft tutorial but now I just want that login functionality integrated in my application. I want that login process in my application. Thanks a ton in advance!

Comment: what type of application is it ? what have you tried ? what is the problem here ? could you please share more information

Comment: I tried to integrate the Azure AD B2C with my application. I want B2C for the login process but now I just want to know that how can I use that B2C built-in login page in my application login page?????? 
Thank you for your response.

Comment: Sorry but it is hard to understand your english... so you'd like to use your login page rather than the b2c login page ? If so it is not possible... but you can customize the b2c login page to look like your app: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-overview

Comment: I would like to use b2c login page rather than my login page in my application. I hope now you can understand my point.

Comment: what is your webapp developped with ? c#, nodejs, java, python ? there are tons of samples on the net....

Comment: C# and I want that types of samples which helps in the integration. If you know any sample so please provide me..

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-tutorials-web-app